# Get all records which falls with in the date range for a given month and year

Tags: sql, date, range

I have a table storing FromDate and ToDate field.
I want to retrieve all the records qualifies for a given month and year. I can not simply use 'BETWEEN' clause become assume the scenario below.
A record has a fromDate '2 Jan 2013' and toDate '15 Aug 2013', I want the query to return this row if my queried month is Aug and year is 2013. Hope I am able to explain what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Please type your query as well and post it, would be easier.

Please clarify the question if this is not what you need.

Edit:

```
Select * 
From table
where FromDate > 01/2/2013 and ToDate < 08/15/2013
```